# How to align text on one column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.col-md-4 {
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">

            <p>
                Test
            </p>
            <p>
                Testttttttttttttt
            </p>


        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jze8gqb1/1838/

I want to align text items in one column. I used display:inline-block but not working. How can I fix? Thank you.

Output

```
          Test
    Testttttttttttttt
```

Desired Output

```
        Test
        Testttttttttttttt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a single `p` tag and `white-space: pre-line`:

```css
.col-md-4 {
  text-align:center
}

p {
  white-space: pre-line;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>
        Test
        Testttttttttttttt
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find more information about the `white-space` property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Answer (score 0):

add this to your class
class="text-left"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p class="text-left">
                Test
                <br>
                Testttttttttttttt
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

No CSS, just add class="text-left" to desired p element